# C# TcpListener AcceptSocket does not work in separate thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, tcplistener

I have a simple TCP server based on the TcpListener. Since I want to use it in a Windows Form application I made it run in a separate thread as follows:

```
 public void Start() {          
        this.serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcess));
        this.serverThread.Name = "Tcp-Server";
        this.serverThread.Start();
    }
 protected void ThreadProcess() {
        try
        {
            IPAddress ipAd = IPAddress.Parse("169.254.42.86");
            this.listener = new TcpListener(ipAd, this.port);
            this.listener.Start();
            Socket mySocket = this.listener.AcceptSocket();
            while (true)
            {                    
                if (mySocket.Connected)
                {                        
                    byte[] RecvBytes = new byte[8192];
                    int byteNo = mySocket.Receive(RecvBytes, RecvBytes.Length, 0);                     
                    ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    mySocket.Send(asen.GetBytes("srv reply msg"));                     
                }
                else
                {
                    WriteLine("socket not connected.");
                }
            }
        }
        finally {
            StopListener();
        }
    }
```

If I use this server in a console application as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {                
            int port = 8001;
            Server server = new Server(port);
            server.Start();                             
            while (true) {
                //server is running in separate thread          
            }   
            ...
```

everything works as expected. However, when I try to include it in a Windows-Form Application that starts the server when a button is clicked, the code doesn't work any more. The server thread is being launched, but it doesn't accept any sockets. 
Is there something that I am missing? I have been searching high and low on google without result...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: I dont see any reason why the code should not work in Windows-Form App. Problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Likely an exception occurs and StopListener is called. This is a TCP connection, a client disconnecting improperly will cause exceptions, you should have a try in the loop to compensate for that

Comment: Could you please post the exact method you use to start the socket in the WinForms app? I suspect it may be something there, but we do not know how it looks...

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but too much to type in the comments:

The easiest way to debug this issue is to simply call the `ThreadProcess()` method in the same thread:

```
public void Start() {          
    ThreadProcess();
    //this.serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadProcess));
    //this.serverThread.Name = "Tcp-Server";
    //this.serverThread.Start();
}
```

You can then step through your code to see what happens. As soon as you hit the `this.listener.AcceptSocket();` line your application will block, but you should be able to connect to it.

Usually the problem is something silly everyone overlooks like the `Start()` method not being called.

Comment: i did just this and, as you said, the application blocks, but the listener still doesn't accept the sockets. I double-triple checked it and the same piece of code works in a console application.

Comment: And `this.port` is the port you're trying to connect to? Also try using `IPAddress.Any` for the listener address instead of hardcoding a specific one.